# How to use the totalTime parameter in ISO 8601 for Google Structured Data?

Tags: iso, structured-data

I'm playing around with Google rich results. I created `HowTo` markup for an article. [The docs.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/how-to)

One of the parameters (in JSON-LD) is `totalTime`. The docs say that this should be given in ISO 8601 format. I would like to say '5 minutes' in ISO 8601 format. How do I use this?

In the docs, Google gives an example: 3 days. This is defined as `P2D`.

I searched on the internet, but I couldn't really find a simple solution about how this works. Can anyone explain the basics of this and how to convert time intervals like "x minutes"?

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This provides a more detailed explanation of the format:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

5 minutes would be PT5M. Period, Time, 5 Minutes.

Answer (score 0):

take this iso 8601 duration generator:
https://www.345tool.com/de/time-util/time-duration-calculator

edit the two dates "from ... to" and you see the totalTime in ISO 8601 String format.